# How do I get the current size of the heap memory of a process in Linux using C/C++ system calls?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory

I am working on a software library, which can constantly keep track of the size of the heap memory of programs written in C/C++.

What I would like to do is as follows.

```
void check_memory(){

  heap_size = get_process_heap_size(.....);

  if(heap_size>=upper_bound){

    //do something to reduce the heap size

    heap_size = get_process_heap_size(.....); 
  }
}
```

Is there any system call in C/C++ that is equivalent to get_process_heap_size() in the code above?

Comment: @Scheff Reading the provided link I do not get how that could solve OPs problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Scheff, malloc allocate using brk and mmap.

Comment: On my linux: /proc/self/maps, self refers to the process that is getting a file descriptor for this file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is any direct system call that gives you memory details, but if you are on linux you can read and parse /proc/(pid of your process)/status file to get the needed memory usage counts